# Check successive similar values and replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of index values like [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5] and another list comprising a characteristic value for each of those indexes like [3,14,6,13,15,3,7,18,4,12,17,2,9]. For the first index of same sequence (e.g. first 2 of [2,2,2]), the characteristic value is always the minimum (e.g. here it is 6), and increases with the number of similar indexes (e.g. for index 2, it increases toward 15).

I would like Python to look for the similar indexes (sequences of index) and then change their characteristic value so that each index gets the minimum characteristic value (e.g. [2,2,2] would have [6,6,6] instead of [6,13,15]).

How can I do it? (or maybe you can indicate me the tools if any)

---

*(this last sentence is less important)*

Also, I need the minimum characteristic value to be <10. If in a sequence of index all characteristic values are >10, I would like to replace them by taking the minimum characteristic value from the previous sequence of index.

Comment: *Indicating tools* isn't what SO is meant for. We could help with *how* if you provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
indices = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
values = [3, 14, 6, 13, 15, 3, 7, 18, 4, 12, 17, 2, 9]
pairs = zip(indices, values)
sequences = [[v for (i, v) in group] for (_, group) in groupby(pairs, itemgetter(0))]
min_char_vals = [min(seq) for seq in sequences for _ in seq]
```

Notice that in your example the lists `indices` and `values` have different lengths. I have inserted an additional `3` item into `indices` to fix this issue.

The following interactive session demonstrates how the snippet above works:

```
In [232]: pairs
Out[232]: 
[(1, 3),
 (1, 14),
 (2, 6),
 (2, 13),
 (2, 15),
 (3, 3),
 (3, 7),
 (3, 18),
 (4, 4),
 (4, 12),
 (4, 17),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 9)]

In [233]: sequences
Out[233]: [[3, 14], [6, 13, 15], [3, 7, 18], [4, 12, 17], [2, 9]]

In [234]: min_char_vals
Out[234]: [3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2]
```

As for the second part of your question, to keep the elements of `min_char_vals` below a threshold, you need to do some in-place post processing on `min_char_vals`:

```
for i, mcv in enumerate(min_char_vals):
    if mcv >= 10:
        min_char_vals[i] = 0 if i == 0 else min_char_vals[i-1]
```

The conditional expression is aimed at assigning a default minimum characteristic value (I used `0` in my code) to the first element of `min_char_vals` when its value is greater than or equal to `10`.

If you change the initialization to:

```
values = [3, 14, 6, 13, 15, 13, 17, 18, 4, 12, 17, 2, 9]
```

and you perform the described post processing, this is what you get:

```
In [280]: min_char_vals
Out[280]: [3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2]
```